# If $(X,d)$ is a metric space, why are $X$ and $\emptyset$ open sets?

Tags: general-topology

My definition of an open set $A$ in a metric space $X$ is that $\forall x\in A\exists y>0: B(x,y) \subseteq X$. How does this theoretically coincide with $X$ and $\emptyset$ being open, looking formally at this?

Comment: Can you make $X$ out of open balls?

Comment: And as for $\emptyset$, *are there any points* in $\emptyset$ which you can't put an open ball $B\subset\emptyset$ around?

Comment: You can think of $\emptyset$ as being open since there are no points in the set which fail the condition. It is also a convenient definition since, if we accept it as true, we can show as a theorem that the intersection of any two open sets is also an open set.

Comment: The empty set being open is what's known as a 'vacuously true' statement:  All universal statements about empty classes are true.   So, for instance,  all currently living female unicorns are pink is a true statement.    It's also true to say all currently living female unicorns are not pink.   It's even true to say all currently living female unicorns are both pink and not pink at the same time :)

Comment: B(x,y)$\subset$X or B(x,y)$\subset$A?

Comment: You can also argue that $\emptyset$ has to be open since the whole space should be closed (of course the limit of any convergent sequence of elements of $X$ should also lie in $X$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x\in X$ then certainly $B(x,1)\subseteq X$, i.e. all points in $X$ that are less than $1$ unit away from $x$ are in $X$.  To express it in the notation you used in the question, one can take $y$ to be $1$.  Actually any positive number in place of $1$ suffices.

As for the empty set, it has no members; thus "all of its members are purple" is true (as long as "purple" means something).  Are all cell phones in the classroom turned off?  If there are no cell phones in the classroom then the answer is "yes". "All cell phones are turned off" means there are none that are not turned off.  "All points in the empty set are withing $1$ unit away from whichever point" means there are no points in the empty set that are not within that distance.  And that is true.  Hence the empty set is open.

Answer (score 8):

For $\emptyset$:

$$(\forall x \in \emptyset)(\exists r>0) \: B_r(x) \subseteq \emptyset$$

is vacuously true, because there are no points in the empty set. So $\emptyset$ is open.

For $X$, there is a catch that you have to keep in mind: $B_r(x)$ is defined to be $\{ y \in X : d(x,y)<r \}$. That is, by definition every member of $B_r(x)$ is contained in $X$. Thus $B_r(x) \subseteq X$ comes for free, so $X$ is open.

This last point can be a little bit tricky when you deal with familiar examples, like subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. For instance this definition implies that $(1/2,1]$ is an open subset of $[0,1]$. This is correct even though $(1/2,1]$ is *not* an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ itself.

Comment: @JimLowe You don't even have to look at what the "predicate" of the statement is. Any statement of the form $(\forall x \in \emptyset) \: P(x)$ is true, because there are no members of $\emptyset$. This is closely related to the fact from propositional logic that $p \Rightarrow q$ is true when $p$ is false.

Comment: @jimlowe Look up vacuously true, and my example in your question above.

Answer (score 0):

$\emptyset$ is open: You have $\forall x \in \emptyset \ldots$ which is true because each forall statement over an empty set is by convention true:

$X$ is open: Not that for each $x\in A$ and $y > 0$ you have $B(x,y)\subseteq X$ because $B(x,y)$ is by definition a subset of $X$ ($B(x,y)=\{z\in X: d(x,z) < y\}$).